# Repeating the same expression multiple in RegEx search, and replace it only one time

Tags: javascript, regex, notepad++

I'm searching for groups of patterns that look like this:

```
[httpUrl](httpUrl "httpUrl")
```

and replace them with:

```
<httpUrl>
```

With a twist: all `httpUrl` must result in the same string and [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions/2759417#2759417).

I already got a start using [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/): matching this pattern in a lazy manner and the twist:

```
\[(http:\/\/.*?)\]\(\1 "\1"\)
```

But I have a problem finding the replacement expression as this doesn't work:

```
<\1>
```

What am I missing here? (I hope it is soo simple that I will say [duh](https://www.google.com/search?q=duh)).

Comment: What language or tool are you using? Your regex is correct, but your replacement string may have to be expressed as `<$1>` for instance depending on the language.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks for that. I was testing in [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) but wanted to use it in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Just found out RegExr wants `$1` and Notepad++ wants `\1`. Like I wrote: `duh`. Please make that into an answer, and I will accept that.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers RegExr is designed for javascript only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most regex flavours have roughly a similar syntax for the basic features, there is not a clear standard as to the syntax of the replacement strings. Some tools use `\1` for referencing strings, others use `$1` and so on.

As you use Notepad++, you should know it uses the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/) for its regex implementation, and it uses the [Boost-Extended format string](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html) for the replacement pattern.

In particular, the placeholder for the n<sup>th</sup> capture group is `$n`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I found a bit more information about back references and capture groups in various libraries on http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html